# BlockUi + JqueryUI dialog: Can't get Ctrl + C to work

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

When a dialog is shown on BlockUI the user can't copy with Ctrl + C (a selected text in the dialog), only right click works.
It doesn't work on all browsers.

My code:
$.blockUI({ message: null });
div.dialog({width: 600 });

I know BlockUI is the problem, does any one know how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the option 'bindEvents' to false.

$.blockUI({ message: null, bindEvents: false }); div.dialog({width: 600 });

Full blockUI options list is here: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#options